# noexec on /tmp and /var/tmp directory

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, security, executable

Our client servers are running old version of jboss (Jboss 4.0) which has lots of known vulnerabilities. Result is that the server is hacked and we are seeing some unknown executable running from `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` and `/dev/shm` directories. The server is being used as a zombie machine from which other machines are targeted.

We modified jboss configuration to remove the flaw with Nessus confirming that the vulnerability is no more there. Apart from that, I executed the following

```
Mounted /tmp with noexec option
Mounted /dev/shm with noexec,nosuid option
```

I had no issue in executing  the above two steps as `/tmp` is on a separate partition for me. I am facing issues with `/var/tmp` location as I cannot use noexec on `/var` partition. So, planning to mount `/var/tmp` on the same partition  that I am using for `/tmp` location. I hoped that will help resolve the issue for me but after executing the changes I noticed that files and dirs in `/tmp` are also available in `/var/tmp`.

```
# ls -l /var/tmp/
total 32
drwx------ 2 ssdg  ssdg   4096 Dec 17 12:10 gconfd-ssdg
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root   4096 Feb 21  2013 hp_sum
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss  4096 Dec 18 11:56 hsperfdata_jboss
drwx------ 2 root  root  16384 May 18  2011 lost+found
srwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      0 Aug 29  2011 mapping-root

# ls -l /tmp/
total 32
drwx------ 2 ssdg  ssdg   4096 Dec 17 12:10 gconfd-ssdg
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root   4096 Feb 21  2013 hp_sum
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss  4096 Dec 18 11:56 hsperfdata_jboss
drwx------ 2 root  root  16384 May 18  2011 lost+found
srwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      0 Aug 29  2011 mapping-root
```

So , probably the idea of using the same partition for `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` is not going to work. Need suggestions how can I implement noexec for `/var/tmp` directory.

Comment: If your server was compromised, start again from scratch. I do not recommend any other way.

Comment: In addition to what @ChrisDown wrote, take the server off the Internet until you have resolved the issue completely. **Leaving the server online is irresponsible even if you believe you have fixed the originally exploited vulnerability.**

Comment: Micheal is right, because if it is a zombie machine it might attack someone else's...

Answer (score 5):

You have no guarantee that programs were only on stored on `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`. I would put them there, as it is less likely that a directory timestamp is detected there, but that doesn't preclude putting executables somewhere else.

Reinstalling the system from scratch—including the version of jboss without the vulnarabilities before going online—is in my experience—little fortunately—the only way to handle intrusions.

Comment: Change *all* passwords, audit databases for unauthorized changes. Search for funny directories, files named `...` or with spaces, ...

Comment: The list to search for is without end, that is why I recommend starting from scratch

Answer (score 1):

You can use mandatory access control (MAC) to restrict if and under which location the JBoss processes may execute other processes.

On Red Hat/Fedora etc. there is SELinux and under Ubuntu there is AppArmor for MAC.

Answer (score -1):

There should be no problem if you bind /tmp to /var/tmp, as there is small chance, that some program will need files in both directories with same names. I advice to go that way.

And it is advisable to add "nodev" option, too.

Some more insights: https://superuser.com/questions/306407/why-bind-mount-var-tmp-to-tmp

Comment: /tmp and /var/tmp have different semantics. /var/tmp is persisted across reboots, which /tmp isn't. Filesystem Hierarchy Standard: [`/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES) and [`/var/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARTMPTEMPORARYFILESPRESERVEDBETWEE).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, additionally, `/tmp` is often very limited in size.

Answer (score -1):

You have to format to secure `/var/tmp`. Set the mount options then. Debian gives you the option, but others may not. Feel free to add `noexec`, `nosuid`, and `nodev` later on.